# Setup for ember-cp-validations

Tags: validation, ember.js, ember-data, ember-validations

I'm trying to integrate ember-cp-validations to my project, so far now the code runs k but when i try to run "validate" methods i receive this error

> Uncaught TypeError: Validator.getDependentsFor is not a function

I tracked down the error to this line

https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations/blob/v2.9.3/addon/validations/factory.js#L436

```
const dependents = Validator.getDependentsFor(attribute, options) || [];
```

which tries to call a function `getDependentsFor` on a Validator object returned here

https://github.com/offirgolan/ember-cp-validations/blob/v2.9.3/addon/validations/factory.js#L434

```
const Validator = type === 'function' ? BaseValidator : lookupValidator(owner, type);
```

as type equals to "presence" it looks for the validator using `lookupValidator` and it's found but the class returned does not have the function `getDependentsFor`, i'm not sure if this is a bug or i'm missing something :/

Versions
Ember                : 2.5.1
Ember Data           : 2.6.1
ember-cp-validations : 2.9.3

```
    import { validator, buildValidations } from 'ember-cp-validations';

    const Validations = buildValidations({
      email: [
        validator('presence', true),
        validator('format', { type: 'email', allowBlank: true })
      ]
    });

    var User;

    User = DS.Model.extend(Validations, {
      ...
    })
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Thanks in advance!!!

Comment: How does your validation look like?

Comment: i just updated the question with part of the code i'm using @jcbvm

Comment: k, looks like the issue was due to i had a file overriding part of the presence validator (i'm trying to replace ember-validations with ember-cp-validations and had a custom presence validator) :(